# Mongo Aggregation - Join two collections based on two fields and get merged document

Tags: mongodb, join, lookup, aggregation

```
For example, let's say you have a users collection and a comments collection and you want to join two collections based on userId and firstName field using lookup and get merged document.
```

Let's say the users collection has the following fields

```
_id
userId
firstName
lastName
country
gender
age
```

And then the comments collection has the following fields:

```
_id
userId
firstName
comment
created
```

And the query I have is

db.getCollection('users').aggregate([ { $lookup: { from: "comments", localField: "userId", foreignField: "userId", as: "usersInfo" } }, { $lookup: { from: "comments", localField: "firstName", foreignField: "firstName", as: "commentsInfo" } }])

How do I join using two field keys - userId and firstName

Please help on this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use conditional lookup with pipeline:

```
[{$lookup: {
           from: "comments",
           let: { userId: "$userId", firstName: "$firstName" },
           pipeline: [
              { $match:
                 { $expr:
                    { $and:
                       [
                         { $eq: [ "$userId",  "$$userId" ] },
                         { $eq: [ "$firstName", "$$firstName" ] }
                       ]
                    }
                 }
              } 
           ],
           as: "user_comments"
         }
}]
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/